# How to convert csv to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, csv, ionic-framework

I am trying to convert csv to array on angular 1.5+ionic on hebrew.
I am using [ng-csv](https://github.com/bahaaldine/angular-csv-import).
What I done till now:

Html:

```
    <ng-csv-import
  class="import"
  content="csv.content"
  header="csv.header"
  header-visible="csv.headerVisible"
  separator="csv.separator"
  separator-visible="csv.separatorVisible"
  result="csv.result"
  encoding="csv.encoding"
  encoding-visible="csv.encodingVisible"></ng-csv-import>
```

my controller is :

```
   .controller('SettingsCtrl', function ($scope,$parse) {
    $scope.csv = {
      content: null,
      header: true,
      headerVisible: true,
      separator: ',',
      separatorVisible: true,
      result: null,
      encoding: 'Windows-1255',
      encodingVisible: true
    };
```

what else should be done to get the object as array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify the code in your controller as

```
     $scope.csv = {
        content: null,
        header: true,
        headerVisible: true,
        separator: ',',
        separatorVisible: true,
        result: null,
        encoding: 'ISO-8859-1',
        encodingVisible: true,
        accept:".csv"
    };
```

and your in your html

```
        <ng-csv-import content="csv.content"
            header="csv.header"
            separator="csv.separator"
            result="csv.result"
            accept="csv.accept">
        </ng-csv-import>
```

$scope.csv.result will now be an array of objects

Comment: hi maybe you know how can I put string to this component to parse it as array? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37700699/parse-string-csv-to-array-on-angular

Answer (score 0):

`$scope.csv.result` will contain the result array from conversion. After the user selects a CSV file from the browse button, it will be populated. So, if you just wanted to do a data dump to the screen:

```
<div ng-if="csv.content">
    {{csv.content}}
</div>
```

Chances are good you want to do more than that when it gets populated, so you can set up a watch on it

```
// (in controller) 
$scope.$watch(
    function() { return $scope.csv.content; }, 
    function(newValue, oldValue) { 
        // do something on change
    }
);
```

Comment: lookd working but on first load app its getting error controllers.js:49Uncaught ReferenceError: csv is not defined(…)(anonymous function) @ VM2442:1InjectedScript._evaluateOn @ (program):145InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap @ (program):137InjectedScript.evaluateOnCallFrame @

Comment: That was my error, the first function passed to $watch needs to return what's being watched, so change it to     `function() { return $scope.csv.content; }`