# convert string csv to array on angular

Tags: arrays, angularjs, csv, ionic-framework

I am using factory to download the file  csv and parse it to array.
I am trying using angular-csv-import to parse my string to array.
My string looks like:

> name,total,table,active ↵דווד,2,1, ↵יוליק גו…, ↵בוריס וטניה ,2,25,
>   ↵גיצה איגור,2,25.....

and my code is:

```
 DownloadFile.all().then(function (fileArray) {
              $scope.csv = {
                content: fileArray,
                header: true,
                headerVisible: true,
                separator: ',',
                separatorVisible: true,
                result: null,
                encoding: 'ISO-8859-1',
                encodingVisible: true

              };
```

then I am using:

```
 $scope.$watch('csv.result', function () {
    if ($scope.csv.result != null) {
```

I can't see that result is firing....
Maybe there is any other library that will format my string to normal array

Comment: It seems like you are changing your whole csv property but watching csv.result. Try $scope.$watch("csv"), function () { ...

Comment: result null...maybe I should take only files instance....do we have anther way to parse this if yes please proved working example of my type

Comment: result will be null because in your code you are assigning it to null, look at it again. you are looking for if ($scope.csv.content != null)

Comment: you are  wrong! please see https://github.com/bahaaldine/angular-csv-import it should rerun result with array...this code was working by directive as upload the file from locally but when I change it to download from url and then give the result of file to content then getting it null...